# What is the best book or site to understand how to construct Periodic Table, theoretically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

I want to understand how [Periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) is constructed theoretically and mathematically.

But I can't find self-contained book or site about it by myself since I'm a computer science guy and lack of knowledge about chemistry and physics.

What is the best self-contained, concise book or site to understand how to construct the Periodic Table, theoretically?

I looked at some chemistry book, but it introduces many concepts (e.g., s-orbit) without definition and I can't understand the theory.

I don't care about the requirements of mathematics and physics knowledge for reading the book, but I want a self-contained book which includes developing theory and mathematics for the Periodic table (e.g., Schrodinger equation).

Comment: Are you basically looking for a book that gives you more detail than the Wikipedia page, but on the same level? There are a lot of things you can read ou of the periodic table, but the construction is relatively simple. For example from top left to bottom right it is ordered by the number of protons in the nucleus of the an atom of the particular element. Electronegativity on the other hand is more a result that you can read from the periodic table, but is not used in the ordering or grouping of the elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. The Wikipedia page includes no formula and I don't feel convinced such kind of explanation. I want to understand how many electrons stay each orbit stably and why it happens and how can we calculate it, and so on. Many books introduce such kind of explanation without calculation and such explanations are not my wants. On the other hand, another kind of books are written only deeply on hydrogen and I can't follow how the theory relates to the Periodic table. I want to understand from basic mechanisms to constructing the periodic table with physics, concisely.

Comment: Understanding spherical harmonics should be very helpful to understand electron orbits: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics

Comment: An interesting fact that there is only one element in existence with all its electron orbits full - palladium.

Comment: Thanks, safesphere. I hope that there exists self-contained material that explains "overview and flow chart" of understanding the periodic table, theoretically. I have too lack of knowledge to collect necessary contents by myself.

Comment: I feel minimul knowledge of quantum mechanics and Schrodinger equation is necessary to understand the overview of the theory.

Comment: So you seem to be looking for a book on the quantum mechanical model of the atom.

Comment: I think the core problem is that you are expecting formula for the periodic table when in fact only the Hydrogen atom can be analyzed to the point of producing detailed formulas.  All other atoms are too complex to be analyzed in that way and solutions for them rely on numerical methods to solve the complex equations and produce only numbers.  Beyond the basic principles of shells there is no precise general formula for what you want, but the basic shell model is good enough to provide the structural basis for the table as it is laid out today.

Comment: Thanks, Javatasse. Yes, probably right. However, since a purple of general quantum theory books doesn't focus on understanding the periodic table and I can't extract what is related to the table and how related the table. If I read the book thoroughly, I will be able to understand but I want to reduce to study  unnecessary contents.

Comment: Thank you very much StephenG. Wow! your comment is the closest answer as I want. A content including your overview explanation and related quantum mechanics formula is the best one I want.

Comment: @safesphere Palladium does not have "all of its electron orbits full" - the $5\text{s}$ shell is empty.

Comment: @probably_someone 50s is also empty, what is your point? All 4 lower orbits are full. No other element has all of its orbits full.

Comment: I would probably recommend starting with (or using as an "anchor" for your studies) the [Electron Configuration page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration) on Wikipedia.  Exactly where you go from there depends on you, of course, but that's what I'd start from to get to grips with the basis of the structure of the periodic table.

Comment: @StephenG Thanks a lot! [Electron Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration) page is great! It doesn't include total theoretical contents but the best indices of my interest. I can expand my knowledge by using it. I'm interested in (1)How can we develop s,p orbital (2) What does numerical methods related to a large number of atoms. Anyway, I reached a position that I can study by myself as your suggestion. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Atomic Orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) is also a nice page for understanding my question.

Comment: try also the wiki page on the shell model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model also the hyperphysics site is a good one for references with more depth http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/shell.html